# Same CSS rule works differently on button and a tag

Tags: css

Here is my HTML-

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.cta {
  background-color: #F07444;
  color: white;
  transition: .2s ease;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'Sans Serif';
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
.cta:active {
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: .2s ease;
  border: 1px solid #F07444;
  color: #F07444;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <button class="btn cta">Abc</button>
    <a class="btn cta" href="abc.com">Abc</a>
    <button class="btn cta">Xyz</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is what it looks at-

[image]

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: it seems you forgot to link bootstrap.css

Comment: @Banzay this example does not require the bootstrap.css.

Comment: @disinfor really? look at this chunk with simply linked bootstrap: https://jsfiddle.net/banzay52/dmcjfz60/

Comment: @Banzay yeah, I think this should be able to be accomplished without bootstrap - however, I do agree that if bootstrap was included it would get the result closer to what OP is looking to do.

Comment: @banzay, I am not using bootstrap here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 properties that can resolve that: setting `vertical-align: middle` and same `line-height` for `.cta`. It looks like browsers set this even when not showing it in inspector.

http://codepen.io/themeler/pen/WRaLzy

```
.cta {
  background-color: #F07444;
  color: white;
  transition: .2s ease;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'Sans Serif';
  line-height: 45px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

Good practice is to use CSS reset in your stylesheet (before other styles).

UPDATE:
Same font size, and removed unnecessary height for button.

UPDATE2:
Damn Mozilla guys are adding border and padding in hidden stylesheet:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Font size is different in the `button` compared to the `<a>` in your pen and with the line-height, the height won't be the same for all elements.

Comment: That's not true (that they'll have different heights), look at updated fiddle - it has `font-size` set to `13px`, and height completly removed from `.btn` (no use for that now when line-height is set).

Comment: Middle element (the `<a>`) is still smaller by about 2px.

Comment: You're right. Sneaky Mozilla guys added some styling and hid it. Now should be fine, codepen updated.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't done anything wrong, it's just that the browser has its own default stylings for some elements, including buttons. It's called the "user agent stylesheet", and if you don't set the properties to override the user agent style, then they stick around.

Right click on the button and click Inspect Element. Look through the Styles tab to see where the user agent is adding its own styles.

Comment: Firefox adds no style. Chrome adds only  "cursor: auto;".

Comment: I can't believe that man with 7 gold badges isn't familiar with code inspector  :)

Comment: @s.k.paul - are you kidding me? Look at the user agent stylesheet for button. Chrome adds a tonne! http://imgur.com/a/cc5GD

Answer (score 0):

There are different properties applied to a link tag and a button tag (some of which aren't seen when inspecting elements).

Instead, you should just wrap the link around the button.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<button class="btn cta">Abc</button>
<a href="abc.com"><button class="btn cta" href="abc.com">Abc</button></a>
<button class="btn cta">Xyz</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is a working JSFiddle to show you: https://jsfiddle.net/nhu6to66/